# Im trying to create my own plugin for the submit review in frontend magento2

Tags: magento2

this one is my **model class**

```
namespace Training1\Review\Model;

class Review
{
    public function aroundValidate(\Magento\Review\Model\Review $review, $name)
    {
        die('test');
    }
}
```

//this one is my di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Review\Model\Review">
        <plugin name="magento-review-model-plugin"
                type="Training1\Review\Model\Review"
                sortOrder="1"
                disabled = "false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: @ManthanDave yes, I've already made my own di.xml and the directories are correct but still not working

Comment: @ManthanDave check it

Comment: Regarding the doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html second argument should be a callable function, but it could not be a problem here, because you have no args. setup:upgrade should helps.

Comment: @NicholasMiller been doing that everytime I change something in my code just in case but still nothing happens

Comment: 1. make sure your module under `setup_module` table (maybe you forget about registration.php)
2. try to add a Magento_Review sequence in module.xml

Comment: @NicholasMiller already has a registration.php file and still not working. probably I missed something

Comment: di.xml looks correct, by the way most of time you no need to define sortOrder and disabled arguments. please make sure your module registered correctly.

Comment: @NicholasMiller already defined those

Comment: put all your structure here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in your **di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Review\Model\Review">
        <plugin name="nameofplugin" type="\VendorName\Modulename\Plugin\CustomReview" disabled="false"  sortOrder="1"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

**My Plugin class :**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

/**
 * Plugin for Custom Review validation
 */
class CustomReview  {

    /**
     *
     * @param Magento\Review\ResourceModel\Review
         * 
         * Aftervalidate function check for special character
     */

    public function aftervalidate(\Magento\Review\Model\Review $review) {

        if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$review->getTitle())) {
            $errors[] = __('Special Characters Are not allowed in title field.');
        }
        else if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$review->getNickname())) {
            $errors[] = __('Special Characters Are not allowed in nickname field.');
        }
        else if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$review->getDetail())) {
            $errors[] = __('Special Characters Are not allowed in comments.');
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
         return $errors;
    }
}
```

After that run **setup:upgrade command** and run **setup:di:compile command**

Comment: Locations of all files - `vendorname/modulename/etc/di.xml`
`vendorname/modulename/etc/module.xml`
`vendorname/modulename/registration.php`
`vendorname/modulename/Plugin/Review.php`

Comment: im good now. thanks for the help. just an admin setting problem

Comment: @AdrianPaul Thanks !! Happy to help , Keep helping :)

Comment: already got everything I needed before making this thread. haha thanks anyways. you helped me a lot